# A question related to Binomial Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

This is a question of an assignment I am solving and I am unable to think about the case when n=odd.

> Let n be a positive integer. Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k}^2 = 0 $  if n is odd .

For n = even integer I was able to prove the required result ( whose statement I am not mentioning) but for this case I am unable to think about it.

Can someone please tell how to prove it.

Comment: Hint: The addends of the sum cancel out in pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Expand both sides of
$$
(1 - x)^n (1 + x)^n  = (1 - x^2 )^n 
$$
and note that $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$.